# How to feed normalized values into Bidirectional LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, lstm

I am trying to build a bidirectional LSTM network with normalized data. I used TF.IDF normalization, so my values are decimal. The dimension I have for the input variable are 2000x50 (numpy.array). 2000 is the number of texts I want to analyze and 50 is the number of words I have in the data (there were more but I brought it down to 50).

The code I built for this is:

```
X_train = np.random.rand(2000,50)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=n_LSTM_units, return_sequences=False)))
model.add(Dense(units=n_dense_units, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=n_epochs, batch_size=batch_size)
```

However, something seems to be wrong, because I am getting an error when fitting the data. I receive the following error:

Input 0 of layer "bidirectional_15" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 50)

```
X_train.reshape((2792, 50, 1))
```

This seems to work, in the sense that the error is gone. However, I am not sure why the model needs the array to be 3-dimensional. Therefore, I am not sure this is the right way. Can someone help with this?

I also found that when reshaping the training data, the code works fine and I don't have to reshape the test data. So `model.predict(X_test)` works fine with 2 dimensions. Why?

Answer (score 0):

The input shape of the model has to be `(x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2])`.

When predicting make sure to have the same shape. If you use `model.predict` you can pass the shape as `(len(x_test), timestamps, features)`.